# how to find JIRA issues that were opened on specific stories, when this story list is changing

Tags: jira, jql, jira-agile

We are working with green hopper and have Stories. When a Bug is opened it is linked to a story through the `'Story Label'` field.

Now I would like to create a query that will show me all bugs related to a sprint, meaning all bugs that relate to the Stories assigned to the sprint.

Here is the query to get all stories:

```
project = TMP AND issuetype = Story AND fixVersion = 11113
```

And Here is the query to get all bugs of a story:

```
project = TMP AND issuetype = Bug AND "Story Label" = jim-887
```

How do I combine both?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the third-party [JQL Tricks plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks%3ajql-plugin). It has a function, hasLinks(), that you could use. For example:

project = TMP and issuetype = story and fixVersion = 11113 and linkedIssuesInVersion(11113,"bug related to story")

More on the usage of that in this [blog post](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/09/get-fancy-with-card-colours-in-greenhopper/).

Thanks,

[Nicholas Muldoon](http://nicholasmuldoon.com/)

[@GreenHopperTeam](http://twitter.com/GreenHopperTeam)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (extraneous spacing added for clarity):

```
project = 'TMP' and( 
      (issuetype = Story and fixVersion = 11113) or 
      (issuetype = Bug and "Story Label" = jim-887)
    )
```